# Can we use AtomicInteger as a local variable in a method and achieve thread safety?

Tags: java, multithreading

```
 public void tSafe(List<Foo> list, Properties status) {
    if(list == null) return;
    String key = "COUNT";
    AtomicInteger a = new AtomicInteger(Integer.valueOf(status.getProperty(key,"0")));
    list.parallelStream().filter(Foo::check).
            forEach(foo -> {status.setProperty(key, String.valueOf(a.incrementAndGet())); }
    );

}

private interface Foo {
    public boolean check();
}
```

> Description:

In the above example, status is a shared properties and it contains a key with name COUNT. My aim is to increment count and put it back in properties to count the number of checks performed. Consider tSafe method is being called by multiple threads, Do I get the correct count at the end? Note that I've used AtomicInteger a as local variable.

Comment: Thread safety is not the kind of thing for which sprinkling around various multithreading constructs produces thread safety.

Answer (score 0):

If you only have one thread, this will work, however if you have more than one thread calling this, you have some operations which are thread safe.  This will be fine provided each thread operates on different `list` and `status` objects.

As `status` is a thread safe collection, you can lock it, and provided the `list` is not changed in another thread, this would would.

In general, working with String as numbers in a thread safe manner is very tricky to get right. You are far better off making your value thread i.e. an AtomicInteger and never anything else.

Answer (score 0):

No this will not guarantee thread safety. Even though `incrementAndGet()` is itself atomic, getting a value from the `Properties` object and setting it back is not.

Consider the following scenario:

1. Thread #1 gets a value from the `Properties` object. For argument's sake let's say it's "100".
2. Thread #2 gets a value from the `Properties` object. Since nothing has happened, this value is still "100".
3. Thread #1 creates an `AtomicInteger`, increments it, and places "101" in the `Properties` object.
4. Thread #2 does exactly the same, and places "101" in the `Properties` object, instead of the 102 you expected.

EDIT:
On a more productive note, a better approach would be to just store the `AtomicInteger` **on your status map**, and increment it inplace. That way, you have a single instance and don't have to worry about races as described above. As the `Properties` class extends `Hashtable<Object, Object>` this should technically work, although `Properties` really isn't intended for values that aren't `String`s, and you'd be much better off with a modern thread safe `Map` implementation, such as a `ConcurrentHashMap`:

```
public void tSafe(List<Foo> list, ConcurrentMap<String, AtomicInteger> status) {
    if(list == null) {
        return;
    }
    String key = "COUNT";
    status.putIfAbsent(key, new AtomicInteger(0));      
    list.parallelStream()
        .filter(Foo::check)
        .forEach(foo -> { status.get(ket).incrementAndGet(); });
}
```

Comment: So.. Do I need to make the AtomicInteger as a static final variable, instead using it as local variable? What are the best practices to use Atomic* to achieve Thread Safety?

Comment: @aravindpogu I've tried to describe a better approach (IMHO, of course) - see my edited answer.

Comment: [putIfAbsent](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentMap.html#putIfAbsent(K,%20V)) requires the key as the first argument, then comes the value: `status.putIfAbsent(ket,new AtomicInteger(0));`

Comment: Stupid omission... I type much faster than I think, unfortunately :-(. Thanks for noticing @Ferrybig (edited and fixed, of course).

Comment: @aravindpogu, A variable is not the same thing as an Object.  if you have two or more threads sharing a single `AtomicInteger` object, it does not matter what kind of variable or how many variables the threads use to access the object.